# Getting the images produced by AzureML experiments back

Tags: data-visualization, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a toy example in Azure.
I have the following dataset:

```
  amounts       city code user_id
1    2.95 Colleferro  100     999
2    2.95    Subiaco  100     111
3   14.95   Avellino  101     333
4   14.95 Colleferro  101     999
5   14.95  Benevento  101     444
6  -14.95    Subiaco  110     111
7  -14.95   Sgurgola  110     555
8  -14.95       Roma  110     666
9  -14.95 Colleferro  110     999
```

I create an AzureML experiment that simply plots the column of the amounts.

[image]

The code into the R script module is the following:

```
data.set <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame  
#-------------------
plot(data.set$amounts);
title("This title is a very long title. That is not a problem for R, but it becomes a problem when Azure manages it in the visualization.")
#-------------------
maml.mapOutputPort("data.set");
```

Now, if you click on the right output port of the R script and then on "Visualize"

[image]

you will see the Azure page where the outputs are shown.

[image]

Now, the following happens:

1. The plot is *stucked* into an estabilished space (example: the title is cut!!!)
2. The image produced is a *low resolution* one.
3. The JSON produced by Azure is "dirty" (making the *decoding* in C# difficult).

It seems that this is not the best way to get the images produced by the AzureML experiment.

Possible solution: I would like

> to send the picture produced in my experiment to a space like the blob
>   storage.

This would be also a great solution when I have a web-app and I have to pick the image produced by Azure and put it on my Web App page.
Do you know if there is a way to send the image somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To saving the images into Azure Blob Storage with R, you need to do two steps, which include getting the images from the R device output of `Execute R Script` and uploading the images to Blob Storage.

There are two ways to implement the steps above.

1. You can publish the experiment as a webservice, then get the images with base64 encoding from the response of the webservice request and use Azure Blob Storage [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179451.aspx) with R to upload the images. Please refer to the article [How to retrieve R data visualization from Azure Machine Learning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/10/24/how-to-retrieve-r-data-visualization-from-azure-machine-learning/).
2. You can directly add a module in C# to get & upload the images from the output of `Execute R Script`. Please refer to the article [Accessing a Visual Generated from R Code in AzureML](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/data_insights_global_practice/2015/12/15/accessing-a-visual-generated-from-r-code-in-azureml/).

Comment: A little warning: the linked articles refer to an old version of Azure. During last week they have introduced a lot of news!

Comment: @AndreaIanni௫, Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image in following way:

```
graphics.off()
png("myplot.png",width=300,height=300) ## Create new plot with desired size
plot(data.set);
file.remove(Sys.glob("*rViz*png")) ## Get rid of default rViz file
```

Comment: I know how to resize the image in R. The issue is how the image is returned by Azure.